# Extra byte(s) at the end of SSL Packet (beyond the length of the packet)

Tags: ssl, openssl

My application is using SSL over SMTP.
But I faced a problem of extra byte at the end.

The packet which I recieved is as follows: (Hex dump of SSL Record packet)

17 *03 01* **01 00** 9A 07 74 E3 4B E0 07 17 71 38 BF 29 7E 70

E9 14 CC B1 97 77 4C B9 AB A0 9F 88 7B D4 ED 14 8E 97 F2

5A BE 46 56 D4 12 BC 15 01 49 EE CE A1 ED 3F D3 6E 7F AA

DC 6B DF 41 11 74 7B 55 B8 D3 3E 8D EF 96 52 B0 BD 50 35

09 E7 2A FF 0E 39 58 C7 91 99 95 22 6F B0 73 57 28 B4 EA

C6 28 4C DC 5C DA 6C 31 FB 63 71 7D 08 F0 DD 78 C4 08 C5

27 90 04 C7 09 59 E4 83 F4 4D 9A 7B 65 E9 AF 38 44 B4 CD

9E 4D BE 80 0D 07 24 8D C3 79 99 DC 02 81 D7 97 21 16 0B

28 44 82 ED E4 5F E6 91 81 A5 28 C1 C8 92 60 36 4E DE 27

AF D0 2B EE FB 9D 12 9C 2B 4F 3F 29 F2 04 8F DC 21 39 4F

80 23 7E 78 3C A0 29 E0 67 E7 9F 90 B6 1F D4 08 63 3E CE

73 E1 17 72 8D B1 8C 3D A8 59 C0 0F 03 59 7A A6 5D F9 7A

40 57 D6 8D 94 48 93 BF D8 17 C6 70 79 36 13 D0 F1 D1 D2

69 D4 05 9D 67 86 6D E9 66 D0 83 4A D8 5E **20**

The length of this packet as seen from SSL 3.1 protocol is 256 Bytes.
But there is one extra byte at the end (shown in **bold** at the end).

Due to this extra byte at the end, when next packet is being read, then this 20 is also read and causes error of **SSL_R_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER** (I am using OpenSSL Library for SSL).
Next packet which I recieved is like (as per packet sniffer)
17 03 01 00 18 ...

But when next read is being done, OpenSSL reads packet as 20 17 03 01 .. which causes the error (since 17 03 is wrong version for 03 01)

I would like to know if this (extra byte at the end) is a part of SSL standard.
Please suggest me how to handle this case in OpenSSL. OpenSSL version is 1.0.0.

Comment: The extra byte is a space. Are you sure you aren't writing it yourself somehow, to the underlying plaintext socket?

Comment: @EJP This is what I received from the server and this is shown by packet sniffer. I used SoftPerfect Network Protocol analyzer. While debugging into OpenSSL, that byte was not read in current packet but in the next packet.

Answer (score 1):

No. The extra byte is not as a part of SSL Standard.

As per SSL Standard (RFC 2246 for TLS 1.0, Latest is RFC 5246 for TLS 1.2) the record of SSL is as below:

```
struct {
    ContentType type;
    ProtocolVersion version;
    uint16 length;
    select (CipherSpec.cipher_type) {
        case stream: GenericStreamCipher;
        case block:  GenericBlockCipher;
    } fragment;
} TLSCiphertext;
```

The fragment will be exactly of the length as specified by `uint16 length` member. So, the 20 must be getting inserted either incorrectly by the Server Implementation, or some other software in the middle is inserting it when the data is in network.

Openssl reads exactly the number of bytes as specified by `uint16 length` member which is why it doesn't read 20.

Some of the points which you can focus on are:
1. Does this happen with the first application data packet which is transferred immediately after handshake? (From the content type I assumed this packet dump is for application data) 
2. Is this a random occurance? Do all connections with that particular server exhibit the same behavior?
3. You can try to get the dump of the packet sent at the Server to see if 20 is present when the packet is being sent at the Server side itself or it is getting added during it's flight.
4. Could there be a Firewall related problem? (I don't know about Firewall, so didn't give more details here)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please elaborate point 1. This is not random occurrence. All connections exhibit same behaviour. Server is a third party server and I cannot access the server to get the dump of sent packet. This problem I am facing after changing OpenSSL-0.9.6 to OpenSSL-1.0.1.

Answer (score -1):

I was bashing my head with this one today; finally resorted to this:

_sslStream.Write(merged, 0, merged.Length - 1)

Problem solved, move along!

Comment: Please take the time to actually read the question and its other answer(s) before posting trivial "answers".  The guy is receiving an extra byte from the server and wondering what to do with it - he is *not* sending an extra byte as your answer might suggest.

Comment: @Dave: I am using OpenSSL library for SSL connection. Martin is right. I am receiving extra byte from the server. This extra byte is causing the problem in read of next message.